# Fatal error in comments.php

Tags: theme-development

I am using customized theme for my development. The site was working fine and in last few days started seeing this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_singular() on a non-object in /home/content/29/11116929/html/studyus/wp-includes/comment.php on line 2399

The error is on line 2399 which is

```
if ( empty( $posts ) || ! $query->is_singular() || ! get_option( 'close_comments_for_old_posts' ) )     return $posts;
```

comments.php is wordpress file and we have not changed anything. 
This is what I have done so far
a) upgraded to latest version 3.9.1
b) disabled all plugins
c) checked comments.php in my theme's file, reverted to base version and still same issues.

This is [my site](http://studyn.us/) and [this is](http://studyn.us/?hloffer=3&cipcode=27&cntlaffi=&fee=&state=&s=gdl-course) where search query is being executed

Comment: Can you please try enabling <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG">WP_DEBUG</a> mode? To do this, just go to wp-config.php include this:

`define('WP_DEBUG',true);`

You might already have a line for WP_DEBUG, so just make sure it's set to true.

Let me know what more errors if any you are getting!

Comment: @VinodDalvi I set it to true and the value is blank in that page

Answer (score 1):

As strange as it may sound, but the error was because in one of the posts I had published , there was - at end!!
So I deleted the posts as that looked like the problem.

Then I restored them one of one and tried to find out what was the problem.

Not sure why that caused the exception to be thrown. Maybe because I was using two shortcodes in the posts abase mysql and table2chart.

Bottom line, do not fiddle with wordpress core files

Answer (score 0):

The error originates from the function `_close_comments_for_old_posts`, which accepts two arguments, `$posts` (array of `WP_Post` objects) and `$query` (`WP_Query` object). As you can see by the error being generated, the problem is that the `$query` passed is not an object.

By default, `_close_comments_for_old_posts` only called through the filter `the_posts`. The `the_posts` filter is, by default, only applied in the `WP_Query` object, passing an array of `WP_Post` object and itself (`&$this`). This is a `WP_Query` object by definition, as it's called from inside `WP_Query`.

Thus, I would say it's good to check if *anywhere* in your code, the `the_posts` filter is applied (by default, it only occurs once, in `wp-includes/query.php`), and check whether `_close_comments_for_old_posts` is mentioned anywhere outside `default-filters.php`.

Comment: I will try this